# Rails 4: How to cancel save on a "before_save" callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have complicated models / forms. I don't want repeated records, so I want to merge records that have similar attributes. How would I cancel "save" using a before_save callback? This is what I'm thinking:

```
class ProductsColor < ActiveRecord::Base


  before_save :check_for_similar_record

  def check_for_similar_record
    if ProductsColor.exist?(color_id: self.color_id, product_id: self.product_id)
      # merge values with existing ProductsColor and stop self from saving
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To prevent record from being saved, you should simply return `false`:

```
def check_for_similar_record
  if ProductsColor.exists?(color_id: self.color_id, product_id: self.product_id)
    # merge values
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: the record will still save if you return nil, you must explicitly return false to cancel the save.

Comment: This is no longer true as of Rails 5 — see the other answer for details.

Comment: @JonGjengset the question was "Rails 4: How to cancel save on a “before_save” callback?". Did I get this down vote from you for this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, I completely missed that. Undone. I only downvoted as I believed the answer was no longer correct, but clearly I was wrong.

Answer (score 81):

## Rails 5

[As of Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17227), you can signal that an operation should be aborted by explicitly calling `throw :abort` inside your callback. The documentation section on [cancelling callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks) (now) states:

> If a `before_*` callback `throws :abort`, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled.

The following section on [transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Transactions) continues:

> If a `before_*` callback cancels the action a `ROLLBACK` is issued. You can also trigger a `ROLLBACK` raising an exception in any of the callbacks, including `after_*` hooks.

## Rails 4

The story is pretty similar to Rails 5, except that callbacks should instead return `false`. The corresponding parts of [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks) helpfully states

> If a `before_*` callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled.

Followed by

> If a before_* callback cancels the action a `ROLLBACK` is issued. You can also trigger a ROLLBACK raising an exception in any of the callbacks, including after_* hooks.

Comment: See also: **Rails 5 throw abort : how do I setup error messages?**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625276/rails-5-throw-abort-how-do-i-setup-error-messages

Comment: What if you want it to silently not save? e.g. prevent duplicate associations in an association table. No need to throw an error in this case... Rails 5

Comment: for implementation you have to do something like `condition ? true : throw(:abort)`

Comment: What if I want a custom message? I use `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved, 'Record already exists'`... To make it more readable, I created a new class `ActiveRecord::RecordExists = Class.new(ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError)` (to initializers), and then `raise ActiveRecord::RecordExists, 'The record already exists'`

Comment: @S.Goswami That's the wrong way to do that. If you want custom error messages, you should use validations.

Comment: Thanks, it's the best way to add custom validations that calls a private method. On errors I think it's good to do this: `errors[:base] << 'Record already exists!'` on the method. It works like the previous comment I wrote, where I defined a new class. But this one is probably a bit better one because I don't have to patch anything, apart from that I am not seeing any reason I won't use the above...