# How to write if else condition in rails before_create hook so that object is saved only when the condition is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save the object in db only when a particular field of the object is legit. For the same, I created a before_create hook in model class in my rails app. How can I add conditional save?

I tried to return false, if the object is not to be saved. However, it did not work, and the object is still being saved/

Comment: Can you add you before create code ?

Comment: please show me the before_create code

Comment: It should be work please have look at link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837573/rails-4-how-to-cancel-save-on-a-before-save-callback/23837592

Comment: Why don't you just add a custom validator?

Comment: use custom validation instead of create callback which is more appropriate  and in that if condition is not true then do `throw(:abort)` return false not works in rails 5+

Answer (score 0):

#### Add a custom validation

For a Test class with a string column `foo`, that must have "bar" or "baz" as value:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord

  validate :foo_check

  def foo_check
    if ['bar', 'baz'].exclude? foo
      errors.add(:foo, "has to be either 'bar' or 'baz'")
    end
  end
```

note that for this specific scenario there already is an easier way to do this, that would be:
`validates :foo, inclusion: { in: %w(bar baz)`
(note that `%w(bar baz)` its equivalent to `['bar', 'baz']`)
I only did the custom validation to show that you can create a validation that can check basically anything.

Here is the guide for custom validations:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods